# Color picker inside jquery UI dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

There is a problem with jquery color picker placed inside UI dialog widget.
Color picker div showed  inside and not over dialog div.

Changing z-index of picker div does not make sense.

```
.evo-pop {
    z-index:9999;
}
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Baa5Q/2/)

[image]

Is it possible to make it shown over dialog div?

Comment: you can set height and width of dialog in options, or write new rules for css overflow of dialog elements

Comment: i tried .ui-dialog with overflow: visible. same behavior

Comment: use browser console to inspect rules, I just adjusted fiddle in console in 30 seconds to make overflow visible. Need to make your rules as specific as the ones in UI css and load them after the UI css loads so they prevail

Comment: finally done
http://jsfiddle.net/Baa5Q/5/